# Synchronizing Google Drive files

Tags: google-drive

Several Windows machines have same account google drive connected as drive. Suddenly I found that new document placed in google drive in one of PC's is not updated in all PC's even on the next day. If I go to https://drive.google.com/ I can see this new file. After I opened Google Drive in browser all PC's was updated with new file.

How to solve problem with not synchronized files?